# Performant spatial join - closest record using SQL Geography functions

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, spatial

When improving closest spatial match performance (geography STDistance) in SQL Server 2012, I have found iteratively stepping up search radius increases performance on our datasets.

I have the below three step query which I am trying to turn into a recursive CTE with max depth 3, with distance comparison [LEVEL]*500.

```
SELECT
    N.WorkID,
    M.WorkID AS MatchWorkID,
    N.Location.STDistance(M.Location) AS Meters
INTO 
    #MatchWork500
FROM 
    NewWork N
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
         C.WorkID, C.Location
     FROM 
         CurrWork C
     WHERE 
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location) <= 500
     ORDER BY 
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location)) AS M
SELECT
    N.WorkID,
    M.WorkID AS MatchWorkID,
    N.Location.STDistance(M.Location) AS Meters
INTO 
    #MatchWork1000
FROM 
    NewWork N
LEFT JOIN 
    #MatchWork500 M500 ON M500.WorkID = N.WorkID
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
         C.WorkID, C.Location
     FROM 
         CurrWork C
     WHERE 
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location) <= 1000
     ORDER BY 
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location)) AS M
WHERE 
    M500.WorkID IS NULL

SELECT
    N.WorkID,
    M.WorkID AS MatchWorkID,
    N.Location.STDistance(M.Location) AS Meters
INTO 
    #MatchWork1000
FROM 
    NewWork N
LEFT JOIN 
    #MatchWork500 M500 ON M500.WorkID = N.WorkID
LEFT JOIN 
    #MatchWork1000 M1000 ON M1000.WorkID = N.WorkID
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
         C.WorkID, C.Location
     FROM 
         CurrWork C
     WHERE 
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location) <= 1500
     ORDER BY
         N.Location.STDistance(C.Location)) AS M
WHERE 
    M500.WorkID IS NULL 
    AND M1000.WorkID IS NULL
```

Each iteration needs to only process what had not been matched previously, into a single CTE table preferably. Please no stored procedure answers, assistance appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to process i.e. N.Location.STDistance(C.Location) <= 1000 if there are no matches for <= 500 in the previous statement, correct?

Comment: Hi @Simon, yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a performant soluton for this (spoiler, I could not find a performant CTE solution). The first step was an improved spatial index on `CurrWork`. The datasets in question both have `Geography` columns. The projection is WGS1984 for reference. This works very fast for most UK based spatial data operations, especially for building/address locations;

```
    CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IDX_Location] ON [CurrWork] ([Location])
    USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
    WITH (
        GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
        CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 3, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

I found I had to use an index hint in my case, this may not always be required.

```
    FROM CurrWork AS C WITH(INDEX([IDX_Location]))
```

To find the closest `CurrWork`, I found a ranked distance worked well as the first step;

```
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY N.WorkID ORDER BY C.Location.STDistance(N.Location),C.WorkID) rnk
```

Then `M.rnk = 1` in the join condition limited to only the closest record. Full code below... hope someone finds it useful!

```
    DECLARE @rad FLOAT = 10000 --10km search radius

    SELECT 
    N.WorkID,
    M.MatchWorkID,
    M.Meters

    FROM NewWork N
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
        SELECT 
        N.WorkID,
        C.WorkID AS MatchWorkID,
        C.Location.STDistance(N.Location) AS Meters,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY N.WorkID ORDER BY C.Location.STDistance(N.Location),C.WorkID) rnk
        FROM CurrWork AS C WITH(INDEX([IDX_Location]))
        JOIN NewWork N ON C.Location.STDistance(N.Location) < @rad
    ) M ON N.WorkID = M.WorkID AND M.rnk = 1
```